# Using IP address as relying party ID in passkey

Tags: spring-boot, webauthn, fido, yubico, passkey

Im trying to implement passkey using yubico passkey library in spring boot and angular and it is working fine in local machine, but when deployed to a server it's not working and showing error.

I currently don't have a domain name, so using the server ip to access the application. Currently im using the ip address as the relying party ID when deployed to the server.

`DOMException: The relying party ID is not a registrable domain suffix of, nor equal to the current domain.`

this is the error shown and it is because of the relying party ID doesnt have a proper domain.

so my question is, is there any way to set the ip address itself as the relaying party ID at least for testing purpose?

Comment: Maybe look for a domain. There are several sites for free subdomains, which should be totally fine for developing. Maybe your server does already have a domain name, try a reverse dns lookup service. In case you only want to test with your machine, an entry in the hosts-file of your OS should work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a domain, I'm afraid. From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#rp-id):

> a relying party identifier is a *valid domain string* identifying…